# .htacces to redirect only if File does not exist

Tags: .htaccess

htaccess on service folder

```
RewriteRule ^images\/(\d+)\/i_(\d+)_p_([\w|\+|\-|\%|\!|\?]+) images.asp?k=$1&i=$2&p=$3 [QSA,L]
```

I need it do this:
https://example/service/images/405/i_0_p_x-320_y-190_cm-1.jpg

If file does not exist on file system then activate the rule above. If file is there then use the file. Images.asp is making those files to filesystem if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to ensure that requested file doesn't already exist. You may also improve your regex a bit to make it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^images/(\d+)/i_(\d+)_p_([^.]+) images.asp?k=$1&i=$2&p=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
```